# How to select different records for ten site in large mysql databases

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a large database of three million articles in a specific category.I'm going with this database, few sites launch.but my budget is low.So the best thing is for me to use a shared host but the problem is that the shared host hardware power is weak given to the user because it shared so I have to get a new post to a site that has already been posted i'm in trouble. I used the following method to get the new contents of the database but now with the increasing number and growing database records more than the power of a shared host to display information at the right time.
My previous method :

I have a table for content
And a table to know what entry was posted statistics that for every site.
My query is included below:

```
  SELECT * FROM postlink WHERE `source`='$mysource' AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT sign FROM `state` WHERE postlink.sign = state.sign AND `cite`='$mycite') ORDER BY `postlink`.`id` ASC LIMIT 5
```

i use mysql

I've tested with different queries but did not get a good result and we had to show a few post more very time-consuming.

Now I want you to help me and offer me a solution thats I can with the number of posts and with normally shared host show in the shortest possible time some new content to the site requesting new posts.
The problem will happen when the sending post stats table is too large and if I want to empty this table we'll be in problems with sending duplicate content so I have no other choice to table statistics.
Statistics table now has a record 500 thousand entries for 10 sites.

thanks all in advance

Comment: Simple solution - You have to scale your hardware to the workload it needs to support.

Comment: Shared hosting increases query response time that's why you need to scale your hardware and should use cloud or dedicated hosting instead of shared. You can look for an affordable dedicated hosting like Cloudways. My site load time decreases to 2-3 seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you seriously calling 3 million articles a large database? PostgreSQL will not even start making Toasts at this point.

Consider migrating to a more serious database where you can use partial indexes, table partitioning, materialized views, etc.